# Symbols inserted in Database but cant fetch full data in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html

I want to insert and fetch the following value from database:

```
~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{POIUYTREWQASDFGHJKL:"?><MNBVCXZ/*-+`123456790-=\][poiuyteeqasdfghjkl;'/.,mnbvcxz/*-+
```

The above values which contains symbols and texts are inserted into database.
But when i fetch those value to a textbox it shows only the following things:

```
~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{POIUYTREWQASDFGHJKL:"
```

How can I get all the symbols and texts in a textbox?
I used `mysql_fetch_assoc` .

Comment: Try using `mysql_set_charset("UTF8");` once and check.

Comment: @Shubham whether i want to insert mysql_set_charset("UTF8");  in that page or i want to insert it in dbconfig file?

Comment: After db connection, you can put whereever you want.

Comment: @shubham I done . But still not getting the full text in the text box

Comment: If you are inserting it via PHP use mysql_real_escape_string on the text.

Answer (score 2):

Please insert the values into the database as given below:

```
$input = "~!@#$%^&()_+|}{POIUYTREWQASDFGHJKL:"?>-+`123456790-=][poiuyteeqasdfghjkl;'/.,mnbvcxz/*-+" ;

$data = mysql_real_escape_string($input);
```

And retrieve the value from database. See if this helps.

Comment: I indented your answer's code, but there appears to be a syntax error somewhere, notice Stack syntax highlighting?